# Error in sending message from server to client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I writing a server program for computing engine in socket programming that displays the average of the numbers given by the client. 
My code for client:

```
main()
{
    //socket
    //connect
    gets(msg);
    f=sscanf(msg,"%f",&num);
    write(sockfd,msg,strlen(msg));
    while ((n1=read(sockfd,result,Z))>0) {
        write(1,result,n1);
    }
}
```

In server:

```
while((rfd=read(sockfd,buff,Z))>0) {
    sscanf(buff,"%f",&num);
    sum=sum+num;
}
sum=sum/n;
snprintf(res,Z,"%f",sum);
write(sockfd,res,strlen(res));
```

The program doesnt work. If I remove the write in server then it is working.
If I just send a sample msg from server to client removing all computation then it works.
Could anyone tell me what is the error

Comment: One problem is that you do not terminate the string you receive. Either send `strlen(...) + 1` bytes or explicitly terminate the strings you receive.

Comment: The `read()` in your server is going to block when the client is finished sending numbers. Ie, it will not return. `read()` will only return once the socket is closed. So instead, your client should preemptively tell the server how many numbers to expect.

Comment: Client program must accept input until user provide --. So I am checking that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Protocol error. The client is writing one number but the server is reading an infinite number of numbers. You need to either (a) change the server to read once, (b) send ahead the number of numbers to read or else (c) shutdown the client socket for output after writing the number and before reading the response.
2. You have a similar protocol error in the other direction. The server is writing one response but the client is looping forever. The server *must* close the socket after writing the reply.
3. You need to add `buff[rfd] = 0' after the read() in the server, otherwise sscanf doesn't know where to stop.